# Restrict invocation of Azure functions to portal and timers

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-functions, azure-security

I'm trying to clear the following recommendation from the Azure portal:

[image: Restrict access to App Services (Preview)]

The App Services in question only exist to host Functions, and those functions are only called by a timer (or, if done manually, through the portal). I don't need them open to the wider internet at all, but I *do* need them visible to the Azure portal itself.

The only settings I see, though, are [IP-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions). Is there a specific set of IPs to whitelist for the Azure portal and timers to still work? (I tried "deny-all", but then I get a message on the function overview page saying "Access restrictions have been added to your function app which may affect your ability to manage it from the portal.")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually the browser making the calls directly. So, the IP you need to add would be the public IP you use to connect to the portal.

This is rather tricky since depending on your ISP, it changes on reconnect but you could always temporarily add the IP when you need to access the details.

If you are using a VPN / Jump Server, you will have to be added its outgoing IP instead and would be simpler if its a Static IP.

Comment: What about when it's triggered by a timer, or blob storage update? Are those considered triggered internally, and need no IP whitelist?

Comment: Yes. This IP restriction is only for incoming IPs, so mainly affects HTTP and Event Grid triggered functions.